# MOSFET class AB power amplifier

Tags: power, mosfet, power-amplifier

I'm trying to design a class AB power amplifier circuit using mosfets by biasing mosfets using current mirror and resistor (R10)

[image]
[image]

I think output voltage is correct, but the problem is that the power consumed by the load resistor is too low...

The power conversion efficiency of this circuit is 1.4%, I don't know if the power consumed by the capacitor should be considered in the calculation, but even with that included, the efficiency is 12.6%

Is this value alright? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If the output voltage is correct, then the load resistor's power is correct. What are you calling the "output voltage"?

Comment: @Hearth Voltage across load resistor. As there is no dead zone distortion, I think the output voltage wave is correct. What I want to know is that the power efficiency of my circuit is too low compared to the efficiency calculated in the Razavi textbook, which is maximum of 75%. The efficiency in the textbook was with respect to BJTs, but mine is too low I think.

Comment: The theoretical maximum efficiency requires certain considerations be made to the bias network and signal levels. I'm going to assume you don't have an optimized bias network, and you're not driving the input as hard as it can go.